# Mount encrypted home during boot (dm-crypt, luks)

Tags: encryption, home-directory, fstab, luks

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my notebook having kept an old luks encrypted partition on my drive.
This partition shows up in the file manager an can be mounted from there into /media/[UUID].
Now I would like to mount this partition during system boot. For that I added

> /dev/mapper/cryptohome /home           xfs     errors=remount-ro 0 2

to my /etc/fstab and

> cryptohome UUID=[...] none luks

to my /etc/crypttab

During boot I am asked for the luks password upon which the /dev/mapper/cryptohome is ready.

While I enter the password the mount command seems to be executed concurrently.
This leads to a failed mount. I am able to mount /dev/mapper/cryptohome manually shortly after the automatic mount failes.

How can I make mount aware that it needs to wait until the luks password is entered successfully?

Thanks,
Philipp

Comment: Are you using LVM on top of the dm-crypt device?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use a app called “Storage Device Manager”. It automatically mounts the device at boot without any hassle for me. maybe that can work for you. Full article about it can be read here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/60817/how-to-auto-mount-partitions-at-linux-startup-the-easy-way/

Comment: No. [Avoid using pysdm for now!](http://askubuntu.com/a/237114/88802)