# Where is the "pysdm" package?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu. I have some old hardware lying around so I decided to build a backup/storage device. I am trying to follow this [lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5919558/turn-an-old-computer-into-a-networked-backup-streaming-or-torrenting-machine-with-ubuntu).

It asks me to open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install pysdm`. However, I keep getting ***Unable to locate package pysdm***. Does anyone know where my `pysdm` is or where I can get one. I have run ubuntu from a usb key and have installed it on a hard drive and get the same message.

Answer (score 16):

Avoid using pysdm for now.

It's been removed from the Ubuntu archives [for a reason](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pysdm/+bug/1005279):

> please remove Pysdm from Ubuntu repositories. It is obsolete (not
>   updated since June 2006 !!), buggy
>   (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pysdm) , doesn't handle
>   UUIDs (which is now fstab standard in all supported Ubuntu versions
>   !!!) and it has already been removed from Debian repositories.

I would suggest to find an alternative for using in recent Ubuntu releases. Also consider reporting this to LifeHacker.

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnBoy Glad I could help. Please consider accepting my answer if you think this is the one. It helps future visitors to point to the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try `Disks` on dash (or `gnome-disks` on terminal) as suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076532), worked very fine as alternative to `pysdm`

This same info is also [here](https://superuser.com/questions/346606/is-there-any-gui-tool-to-configure-etc-fstab).

Comment: Does not work for me - `E: Unable to locate package gnome-disks`

Comment: @Domi `apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`

Comment: It has the option I was looking for, to mount partitions at start.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use the `pysdm` package from Ubuntu 12.04.

Downloadlink: http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pysdm/pysdm_0.4.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb

Download it and install it with `sudo dpkg -i pysdm_0.4.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb`.

Comment: Would it be wise to set up a **Storage device manager** designed for another release? There's [a reason for it](http://askubuntu.com/a/237114/88802) to be removed.